# Parsing POST body in R Rook

Tags: r, post, r-rook-package

I would like to get the raw text of a POST request's body using the R web server package Rook.

I have registered the R app:

```
parsePOST <- function(env) {
  request <- Rook::Request$new(env)

  body <- request$body()
  print(body)
}

R.server$add(app = parsePost, name = "reportGeneratorApp")
```

Unfortunately, `body` is a `Rook::RhttpdInputStream`. Things I've tried:

1. This provides only the first line:
   `body <- request$body()$read_lines()`
   Result:
   `{\n`
2. This provides only the start of the body, regardless of the "Content-Length" header. All other read lines are `character(0)`. Additionally, the lines have missing data in random places.
   `body <- request$body()$read_lines(10)`
   Results:

```
   [2] " \"data\": {\n   "                                                                                                                        
   [3] "evious\": [\n      2\n    ],\n    \"v"                                                                                                    
   [4] "e\": {\n        \"Differentially private me"                                                                                              
   [5] "              \"values\": [\n                44.39"                                                                                       
   [6] "an mechanismLaplace\"\n              ],\n              \"arguments\": ["                                                                  
   [7] "         },\n            \"batch\": [\n              1\n            ]\n          }\n    "                                                 
   [8] "\n            ]\n          }\n        }\n      },\n      \"educ_income\": {\n        \"ols\": {\n          \"ols0\": {\n            \"rel"
   [9] ""                                                                                                                                         
  [10] ""
```

The POST request is being sent by postman, with the header `Content-Type: application/json`.

I'm very surprised to find it so difficult to retrieve the request body.

Comment: So hard to help on this one without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extract the body as a string with the following:

`writeLines(paste0(rawToChar(request$body()$read(), multiple = T), collapse=""))`

The `read()` method returns bytes, I parse each byte into a character vector, and then collapse the character vector. If anyone has an easier or cleaner way to do this, please share.